# How to add null-character to string in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to create string in perl with length, for example 7, but "visible" contents, for example "a".

my $test = ...;

print $test result: "a"
print length($test) result: 7

Comment: What possible use could this have?

Comment: @Ether null-padding of strings has use in cryptography applications.

Comment: @Ether This is also required sometime when you do a syscall() from perl and when data are passed-in back through a pointer. In such a case, the string must be long enough to receive data. The common way to do this is to pre-fill your string with null values such as "my $pointer = "\0"x1024;"

Comment: Also: if you write a script that feeds to, for example, `xargs -0`

Answer (score 13):

You add null characters to the string. Why you want to this is beyond me, but how you do it is shown below.

```
{ow-loopkin:tmp:->perl
$string = "e\0\0\0\0";
print length $string;
[ctrl+d]
5
{ow-loopkin:tmp:->
```

You can also use pack() to pad it with nulls:

```
ow-loopkin:tmp:->perl
$string = pack("Z6", 42);
print length $string;
[ctrl+d]
6
{ow-loopkin:tmp:->
```

Comment: You could also use the x string operator: $string = 'e' . "\0" x 42;

Answer (score 0):

A usage example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

require 'syscall.ph';

my $path = '/root/target';
my $buf = "\0"x512; # $buf (pointer) must be large enough to receive data

# See statf(2) on Linux
syscall(&SYS_statfs, $path, $buf) == 0 or die($!);

my @st = unpack 'L7', $buf;

print Dumper(\@st);

1;
```

Answer (score -1):

See the [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) function, perhaps.